# issue with adding node to a list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I have a piece of code where I am trying to add a node to make list from empty linked-list. Subsequently it keeps adding to the end of the list. One block of code I had, only keeps last two nodes. Suppose if I add two elements - 10, 11 it works fine. But when I do 11,12,13,14 it only keeps 13,14. I have a work around which works fine, but want to know what is causing this behaviour. Code block is below. Issue is with AddList function only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    struct Node {
            int data;
            struct Node* next;
    };
    
    void AddList(struct Node** node, int value) {
            struct Node* new = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            new->data = value;
            new->next = NULL;
            if (*node == NULL) {
                    *node = new;
                    return;
            }
            while ((*node)->next != NULL) {
                    *node = (*node)->next;
            }
            (*node)->next = new;            
            return;
    }
    void PrintList(struct Node** node) {
            printf("\n\n");
            if (node == NULL) {
                    printf("\n\nList is empty !! Nothing to Print. \n\n");
                    return;
            }
    
            while (*node != NULL) {
                    printf("%d--> ", (*node)->data);
                    *node = (*node)->next;
            }
            printf("\n\n");
            return;
    }
    
    void main() {
            struct Node* head = NULL;
            AddList(&head, 10);
            AddList(&head, 11);
            AddList(&head, 12);
            AddList(&head, 13);
            AddList(&head, 14);
            PrintList(&head);
    }
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does wrong?

Comment: `*node = (*node)->next;` That changes the original list pointer. That's not what you want. Use a temporary pointer variable instead.

Comment: Have not run a debugger yet, but work around is, if i use a extra pointer variable, struct Node* current = *node; and traverse it through the while loop, while(current->next != NULL) current = current->next; } current->next = new; return; it works fine !

Comment: @kaylum did not quite get that. I have to walk the list to go to the end, what is wrong in this walk ??

Comment: You are using the original `head` pointer to traverse the list. It means you lose the original `head` value every time you traverse the list. You are effectively doing `head = head->next`

Comment: So, I am changing the head address ?? hmmm probably I have miss calcualated while dealing with dealing with 2nd level pointer !!

Comment: 'if (node == NULL) {' will always be false, so you will never get 'List is empty !! Nothing to print'

Comment: @Martin James - Yep that was a typo I guess. code should have been if(*node == NULL) Actually,  the PrintList function does not need reference to the head or 2nd pointer. Only sending head will do. But I was experimenting something. Thanks for pointing to the error !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the same error in both functions `AddList` and `PrintList`. The both functions accept the pointer to the head node by reference as for example

```
AddList(&head, 14);
PrintList(&head);
```

So if the functions change the pointed pointer to the head node then its value is changed.

And indeed the pointer to the head node is changed within the functions.

In the function `AddList` this loop

```
while ((*node)->next != NULL) {
        *node = (*node)->next;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

changes the value of the pointer to the head node.

In the function `PrintList` the pointer to the head node is even set to NULL due to this while loop

```
while (*node != NULL) {
        printf("%d--> ", (*node)->data);
        *node = (*node)->next;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Also in the function `PrintList` the condition in the if statement

```
 if ( node == NULL) {
         printf("\n\nList is empty !! Nothing to Print. \n\n");
         return;
 }
```

does not make a sense. That is the pointer node can be equal to NULL but this does not mean that the current list is empty.

The functions can be defined the following way

```
int AddList( struct Node **head, int data ) 
{
    struct Node *new_node = ( struct Node* )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and

```
void PrintList( const struct Node *head ) 
{
    printf("\n\n");
    if ( head == NULL ) 
    {
            printf("\n\nList is empty !! Nothing to Print. \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next ) 
        {
            printf( "%d--> ", head->data );
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

There is no need to pass the pointer to the head node to the function `PrintList` by reference. That is the functions can be called for example like

```
AddList( &head, 14 );
         ^^^^^
```

and

```
PrintList( head );
           ^^^^
```

If you are adding new nodes to the tail of the list then itwill be much better to define a tw-sided singly-linked list. That is you could introduce one more structure like

```
struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

and

```
struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};
```

In this case the function that adds new nodes to the tail of the list would be much more efficient because there is no need to traverse all nodes of the list.

Bear in mind that according to the C Standard the function `main` shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

instead of

```
void main()
```

Comment: Great !! You have notified me an un-detected bug !! I was experimenting. Agreed, PrintList function does not need poniter to pointer or reference to the head !! But I was experimenting.. and since I am also printing the vlaues inside the while loop, it worked just fine without error !! But when I call the PrintList function 2nd time, boom - that did not print anything...bug was detected !! Thanks for your analysis !!!

Comment: Agreed on extra pointer variable for the AddList function that helps to add a node in O(1) rather than O(n) - n being the no of nodes. I have one clarification though for selection of the for loop for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next ) inside PrintList function that you have modified. Is anything wrong with the while loop ??

Comment: Perhaps the for loop in the PrintList function makes the code more readable and concise ??

Answer (score 0):

This modification corrects the issue: A new variable struct Node* current is added

```
void AddList(struct Node** node, int value) {
        struct Node* new = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        struct Node* current = *node;
        new->data = value;
        new->next = NULL;

        if (*node == NULL) {
                *node = new;
                return;
        }

        while(current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new;
        return;
}
```